# An inequality for functions in $L^1$ and $L^2$.

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

Given $f\in L^1(X)$, show that for every $\rho>0$ one has:

$\mu({|f|>\rho})\leq \rho^{-1}\int|f|d\mu$.

I think in order to prove this, we use the fact that $\int|f|d\mu= \lim_{\rho\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho\mu(|f|>n\rho)$. Am I correct in assuming that the inequality more or less follows from this?  I was also wondering if we could make a stronger/similar statement for $L^2$ functions.

Comment: Why should the mentioned equality hold? On the left-hand side $\varrho>0$ is fixed whereas on the right, you let $\varrho \to 0$.

Comment: I brought the $\rho$ to the other side now.

Comment: I see. Then: Yes, the inequality follows from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\mu(|f| > \varrho) = \int_{|f|> \varrho} \, d\mu \leq \int_{|f|>\varrho} \frac{|f|}{\varrho} \, d\mu.$$

This inequality is known as *Markov's inequality*.

**Remark:** For $f \in L^p(\mu)$, $p \geq 1$, $$\mu(|f|>\varrho) \leq \frac{1}{\varrho^p} \int |f|^p \, d\mu.$$